# PHP - Formatting a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I make my daily NBA schedules using the nba.com site [here](http://stats.nba.com/schedule/#!/?rfr=nba), but they changed the layout of it now it contains more data. Using PHP, I was able to turn

this:

```
5:00 PM ET
LA Clippers
Charlotte Hornets
Spectrum Center
Charlotte, NC
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
```

into this:

```
5:00 PM ET
LA Clippers
Charlotte Hornets
```

However, I am having difficulties turning that into this:

```
5:00 PM ET LA Clippers @ Charlotte Hornets
```

I am open to suggestion even other languages like javascript/jquery that I could implement into a userscript if not PHP.

any suggestions?

code I'm currently using to clean the words i don't want.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["teamname"];
$words = array("Spectrum Center","Charlotte, NC","Bankers Life Fieldhouse","Indianapolis, IN","Wells Fargo Center","Philadelphia, PA","Quicken Loans Arena","Cleveland, OH","bc","Chesapeake Energy Arena","Oklahoma City, OK","Toyota Center","Houston, TX","American Airlines Center","Dallas, TX","GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS","Vivint Smart Home Arena","
Salt Lake City, UT");
$name = str_replace($words,"",$name);

if(isset($_POST["teamname"])){
    echo 'output:<br /><br /><textarea name="teamname" cols="80" rows="20" onclick="this.focus();this.select()">'.$name.'</textarea>';
    }
?>
```

edit: added my code.

Comment: Paste in the code you've got already so SO users can help you modify it.

Comment: change your last line break to an @. relly need to see your current code on this one

Comment: added the PHP code i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `javascript` you can call `.split("\n")` on string, then use `Array.prototype.splice()` to add one or more elements to array, then call `.join("")` on array to return string.

```js
let data = `5:00 PM ET
LA Clippers
Charlotte Hornets
Spectrum Center
Charlotte, NC
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS`;

let arr = data.split("\n").slice(0, 3);
arr.splice(-1, 0, " @ ");
arr.splice(1, 0, " ");

console.log(arr.join(""));
```

Given string at jsfiddle, with `"bc"` omitted at line `26`, you can use a `do..while` loop, increment a variable by `6` to skip three lines before next date line.

```js
let data = `5:00 PM ET
LA Clippers
Charlotte Hornets
Spectrum Center
Charlotte, NC
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
7:00 PM ET
Milwaukee Bucks
Indiana Pacers
Bankers Life Fieldhouse
Indianapolis, IN
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
7:30 PM ET
Miami Heat
Philadelphia 76ers
Wells Fargo Center
Philadelphia, PA
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
7:30 PM ET
Denver Nuggets
Cleveland Cavaliers
Quicken Loans Arena
Cleveland, OH
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
8:30 PM ET
Golden State Warriors
Oklahoma City Thunder
Chesapeake Energy Arena
Oklahoma City, OK
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
9:00 PM ET
Phoenix Suns
Houston Rockets
Toyota Center
Houston, TX
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
9:00 PM ET
Orlando Magic
Dallas Mavericks
American Airlines Center
Dallas, TX
GAME PREVIEWBUY TICKETS
10:00 PM ET
Boston Celtics
Utah Jazz
Vivint Smart Home Arena
Salt Lake City, UT`;

let [arr, n, next, res] = [data.split("\n"), 0, 6, Array()];

do {
  let curr = arr.slice(n, n + 3);
  curr.splice(-1, 0, " @ ");
  curr.splice(1, 0, " ");
  res.push(curr.join(""));
  n += next;
} while (n + next < arr.length);

console.log(res);

var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    text += res[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this example, but when I add more than one team it only reads the first, would I have to add a for loop?

Comment: Yes. You can request N teams using `Promise.all()`, `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`, then iterate response array to perform same action on each response.

Comment: i tried a for loop, but i was only able to get the array from the loop if i commented arr.splice(-1, 0, " @ ");
arr.splice(1, 0, " "); otherwise i just got the first entry.

Comment: Note, the approach parses string at `javascript`, not `php`. Used the string at original Question.  Are newline characters included in returned string?  Can you reproduce getting the string described at Question at stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here you can see the part I commented, if I leave the slice, then it only shows one event. https://jsfiddle.net/8d458kmg/3/

Comment: Is `bc` at line `26` in actual string?